# How does the highlight indicating available Review Queue works?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, notifications, review-queue

I recently reached the 2k milestone, granting me access to the Low Quality and [Suggested Edits](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits) Reviews. I noticed that now I can access those queues, I now get *notifications* when some of them are available, it looks something like this:

[image]

However, I never received that notification before, with First Posts and Late Answers Review queues. I also noticed that now I get those notifications **only** for Suggested Edit reviews, not for any other of the queues I have access to (First Posts, Late Answers, nor Low Quality Posts).

This I verified by manually going to the [Review](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/review) page and seeing that there were some First/Late/Low Quality posts available, but never received notifications for those.

I read the [original feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191638/notify-users-of-possible-reviews-on-toolbar) but could not understand why the explained behavior. **How does the review notification work here in TWP?** I am trying to understand better how things work around here.

Comment: I am afraid it is probably best you just ignore that number. See here for more details: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238699/202356

Comment: @MaskedMan Yeah that meta is arguably the most official word on it but in my experience the number is *always* off. Reviews that need additional input, that you've skipped or that you just don't see in the queue for some reason will virtually always cause that number to remain greater than zero. About the only time it will go to 0 is when there are a few other people going through the queues at the same time.

Comment: @Lilienthal That is my experience with it as well. For a couple of weeks, I tried guessing how it works, then I just realized that was a stupid idea, and gave up on it. I now look at it as just another random number. ;)

Comment: It gets even worse when you hit 10k and add all the questions with delete votes.

Comment: Thanks guys. Your comments are really useful. Should an answer be elaborated from them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This main meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238699/202356) suggests that, for all practical purposes, the number is meaningless and it is best to just ignore it. shog9 summarizes the reason eloquently in the first paragraph:

> Caching. And some complicated eligibility rules.

... and follows it with three short paragraphs of <s>[Techno Babble](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TechnoBabble)</s> explanation of how the number is calculated behind the scenes and what makes it an unreliable indicator of what *you* actually see in the review queues.